# How to Skip implementation of interface in class

Tags: c#, oop, interface

Interface - I1 (contains M1 method)
Class - C1:I1 (c1 implements I1)
Class - C2:C1 (C2 inherits C1)

```
interface I1
{
    void M1();
}
class C1 : I1
{
    void M1(){}
}
class C2 : C1
{
}
```

Requirement:
**There should not be any implementation of "M1" in "C1"**, basically "M1" needs to be implemented in "C2"

How to achieve this using any of the OOPs concepts?

Comment: I've added an outline of your first line that is easier to understand (IMO), please feel free to modify or revert back if you do not believe this is acceptable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `C1` abstract and define `M1` as an abstract method.

Answer (score 9):

As long as you can tolerate C1 being abstract, this works:

```
interface I1
{
    void M1();
}

abstract class C1 : I1
{
    public abstract void M1();
}

class C2 : C1
{
    public override void M1()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Edit**: As Isantipov noted in the comment  you can avoid the abstract class like this:

```
class C1 : I1
{
    public virtual void M1()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you can't have c1 abstract the only thing you can do (apart from changing your architecture to avoid inheritance) is to make M1 vertual and throw NotSupportedExcetion (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) in its C1 implementation)

Comment: Thank You David, got the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for abstract [method<sup>[wiki]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_method#Abstract_methods):

> An abstract method is one with only a signature and no implementation
>   body. It is often used to specify that a subclass must provide an
>   implementation of the method. Abstract methods are used to specify
>   interfaces in some computer languages.

[Abstract methods in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> An abstract method declaration introduces a new virtual method but
>   does not provide an implementation of that method. Instead,
>   non-abstract derived classes are required to provide their own
>   implementation by overriding that method. Because an abstract method
>   provides no actual implementation, the method-body of an abstract
>   method simply consists of a semicolon.

In your case:

```
interface I1
{
    void M1();
}

abstract class C1 : I1
{
    public abstract void M1();
}

class C2 : C1
{
    public override void M1()
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either make C1 abstract or you can use Explicit implementation. This means it is implemented, but it is not visible.

```
class C1 : I1
{
    void I1.M1(){ throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

It is invalid to call it like this:

```
C1 c1 = new C1();
c1.M1(); //Error
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer.
You could have multiple interfaces. [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K7oEAf)

```
interface I1 
{
   void someCommonMethod();
}

interface I2 
{
   void M1();
}
```

Then your classes can inherit like this.

```
class C1 : I1
{
    public void someCommonMethod()
    {
        ...
    }
}

class C2 : C1, I2
{
    public void M1()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```